# Should we rephrase this old question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I stumbled on [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/what-is-considered-sharp-enough-w-r-t-the-landscape-pictures-from-a-dslr-with?rq=1) by pure chance, and noticed that:

1. The focus of the question is a linked picture, but the link is broken
2. Picture aside, the question is written in a somehow convoluted way
3. The core of the question is interesting and the accepted answer very good

I've tried to find the picture again, but with not much luck (and not much effort, too, tbh). Should we try to rewrite it, keeping the original intent so that it focuses only on what the OP wanted to achieve and removing any mention of an example picture?

Comment: Guessing this is the photographer's site. 
http://www.mg-photo.net/landscape_photography.php

Answer (score 3):

The answers don't seem to mention the photo, so yeah I'd just edit the question to remove the link, and perhaps any mention of it specifically.

Comment: Ok, I was waiting for a larger approval, but I see not much interest in it. I'll wait another day, and then if no one object I'll edit the question. I mean, it has been there for 7 years, it can wait a day more :-D